# How I remove the needle in string

Tags: php, string, strstr

How can I remove the **"-"** in my string?

```
$text  = 'lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet!';
$lorem = strstr($text, '-');

echo $lorem;
```

return:

**- dolor sit amet!**

And I need this:

**dolor sit amet!**

Comment: `$parts = explode('-', $text); $wanted = trim($parts[1]);`

Comment: Or use `ltrim($lorem, '- ')` on the result you already have...

Comment: do you mean something like `$var = str_replace ("-", "", $text);`

Comment: just use str_replace ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple enough to use `explode()`. Use `list()` with it to make it a one-liner and give the variable a clear name (i.e. not use array syntax like `$parts[1]`).

```
list(,$dolor) = explode(' - ', $text);
echo $dolor;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet!';
$pos = strpos($str,'-');
echo substr($str ,$pos+1,strlen($str));
```